# Pymongo default journaling

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, insertion, journal, durability

When using pymongo (since 2.4), when doing  this :

```
m = pymongo.MongoClient()
m.write_concern = {'w': 2}
m.write_concern['j'] = True
```

We specify that we want acknowledged (on 2 replicas) and journaled write.

If we mention nothing in the write concern it sounds like w = 1 by default according to this [post](http://emptysqua.re/blog/pymongos-new-default-safe-writes/).
But what is the deault mode for journaling when we specify nothing, is it j= True or False ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `j` option is `False` by default. With journaling disabled on the `mongod`, inserting a document with default settings succeeds. If `j` was `True` by default it would have raised an exception.

Comment: Please note that 2.6 errors out with j:true if journal is disabled, where 2.4 just ignores j:true: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/

Be aware of performance implications of j:true - it will limit the rate of inserts to 30/sec per each thread, because journalCommitInterval will be 30msec and each write with j:true will have to wait for journal to commit.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just used it for testing pymongo. `j` defaults to `False` anyhow.

Comment: Thx. Your answer and comments leads me to new questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344559/mongodb-journaling-is-the-journal-file-used-when-the-client-request-a-non-jour